# Printing numpy array with indicies

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

The following code will print the values in a numpy array preceeded by array indices.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
for index, val in np.ndenumerate(a):
    print(index, val)
```

It will print the following:

```
(0,0) 0
(0,1) 1
(0,2) 2
(1,0) 3
(1,1) 4
(1,2) 5
```

Is there a way to extract out the index values so each value can be printed separated by a comma similar to this?

```
0,0,0
0,1,1
0,2,2
1,0,3
1,1,4
1,2,5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the values in your tuple `index`, use their indices. And you can use string formatting to print the string how you want. See this for more information: 
https://pyformat.info/

You could do the printing like this:

```
>>> for index, val in np.ndenumerate(a):
...     print '{}, {}, {}'.format(index[0], index[1], val)
...
0, 0, 0
0, 1, 1
0, 2, 2
1, 0, 3
1, 1, 4
1, 2, 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
for index, val in np.ndenumerate(a):
    print(index[0], index[1], val)
```

This worked for me. You might want to do the print part dynamically if the array will change sizes, but if it's a one off piece of code I think this is fine.